# How can I download lambda code from an S3 link in a CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a CloudFormation template from an AWS Image Handler example
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler

Here is the template:
https://solutions-reference.s3.amazonaws.com/serverless-image-handler/v3.1.1/serverless-image-handler.template

It points to an S3 Bucket where it downloads the Lambda code from

`S3Bucket: solutions
S3Key: serverless-image-handler/v3.1.1/serverless-image-handler.zip`

How can I download what is in that zip file?

Comment: well, you can't if you don't own the bucket or the bucket is not public. But I really don't get what you are trying to do given the code is available under source/ on github.

Comment: How does my lambda retrieve the code from the bucket then?
This is trying to download a patch that is undocumented in the github repo.

Comment: The repo owner shows how to do it in the README.md. Essentially you need to build the code with `build-s3-dist.sh` and copy the zip file it to *your* bucket (mind that you need to create this bucket yourself) with the commands `aws s3 cp ./dist/ s3://$DIST_OUTPUT_BUCKET-[region_name]/serverless-image-handler/$VERSION/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.zip"` and 
`aws s3 cp ./dist/serverless-image-handler.template s3://$TEMPLATE_OUTPUT_BUCKET/serverless-image-handler/$VERSION/`

Comment: The problem is the patch is not in the github repo so building out of the repo wont reflect the change I need. Where as the S3 their CloudFormation points to has run that build script over a change I need. So I was hoping to download the S3 version to see what update I need to do.